# Is library file present in .apk file?

Tags: android, apk

Actually I want to know that if in my application's libs folder, any library file(e.g .jar file) is present, then after installing(running) that application, will library file present in .apk file?
According to my understanding, library FILE should present in generated .apk file. If I am wrong then please correct me.

If my question is below standard, then extremely sorry for that. Any help will be well appreciated

Comment: surely jar file and images and everything which is belongs to ur .apk is here on ur .apk file

Comment: @HCD what does "ur" mean? Can you please edit your comment to use proper words?

Comment: @GrahamBorland my means is <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_(file_format)>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With recent versions of the Android tools, .jar files in the libs folder are automatically included in the build. (See [Dealing with dependencies in Android projects](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects).) So, yes, the library is included in the compiled bytecode (not as a separate file).

If you use ProGuard in a release build, then it will attempt to strip out any code which is not actually used. So, it may be that *some parts* of the library are included in the final .apk, and some parts are removed.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is yes. The apk is just a zipped version of your compiled project. If you open it with winrar for example, youll see that everithing is in there ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it and see yourself but you can not directly see the .jar file under libs folder in the apk generated. Library class files are all together are compiled into a single .dex file. If you decompile that dex file, you can reach the java codes.